# create temporarty non persistent object in Ember-Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want create an object using ember-data, but I don't want to save it until I call commit. How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `transaction`'s, defined [transaction.js](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/transaction.js) with corresponding tests in [transaction_test.js](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/unit/transaction_test.js).

See an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/7knGg/):

```
App.store = DS.Store.create(...);

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});

var transaction = App.store.transaction();
transaction.createRecord(App.User, {
    name: 'tobias'
});

App.store.commit(); // does not invoke commit
transaction.commit(); // commit on store is invoked​
```

Answer (score 1):

Call createModel instead!

Example:

```
// This is a persisted object (will be saved upon commit)
var persisted = App.store.createRecord(App.Person,  { name: "Brohuda" });

// This one is not associated to a store so it will not
var notPersisted = App.store.createModel(App.Person,  { name: "Yehuda" });
```

I've made this http://jsfiddle.net/Qpkz5/269/ for you.

Comment: You are using `ember-latest.js` from the downloads section of the data repository. This file has been uploaded 2 months ago (2011-01-30) and is outdated. I haven't found this method in the code from master.

Comment: @pangratz is right, I hadn't notice that this was changed. Kudos him

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_create`: `App.MyModel._create()` - it will associate the model with its own state manager, so `App.store.commit()` won't do anything.

However, `_create` is "private". I think there needs to be a public method for this use case.